# Extract filelocation from a sentence

Tags: java, regex

Input is being read from console and stored in string, trying to make pattern to get file path along with filename.extension
if not than just filename.extension (without path also works)

Sample input string:

```
[blah]: Destination folder is: part1/part2/part3/
[blah]: SP status: 
  .....
[blah]: moving fileNameNeeded.Extension to part1/part2/part3/fileNameNeeded.Extension
[blah]: moving done...
DC data collected at part1/part2/part3/fileNameNeeded.Extension
[blah]: Elapsed time
```

Pattern tried:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^/.]+(?=\\.*?tar$)");
```

also tried:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\bDC data collected at.*?tar");
```

Output:

```
DC data collected at part1/part2/part3/fileNameNeeded.Extension
```

but getting additional output as well (don't want to use string split).

I did checked post: [Extract part of a string from a URL - Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541500/extract-part-of-a-string-from-a-url-java-regex) but I am not very familiar with Regex.

Any help/suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
^(\/.+\/)*(.+)\.(.+)$
```

Input : `/path/to/some/file.txt`

```
1.  [0-14]  `/path/to/some/`
2.  [14-18] `file`
3.  [19-22] `txt`
```

[Click here to see how it works and experiment!](http://regex101.com/r/xO7oS1/3)

Comment: using your pattern in eclipse says invalid syntax, after modifying with  `^(.+\\/)(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)$` its not working.

Comment: works fine for me, been using it in production systems for years, ***its not working*** doesn't mean anything

Comment: @Ankit what does eclipse say?